# Explanation for magnetic declination

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, magnetic-monopoles

A compass in New York points about 15 degrees west of true north; in California, it points about 15 degrees east of true north. Magnetic declination also varies with time. What are some possible explanations for magnetic declination?

Comment: It's all to do with earth's liquid, molten iron core and its internal flow over time.

Answer (score 1):

The Earth's magnetic field is generated by a complicated process that involves convective motion of molten materials hundreds of miles below the surface, as well as by fields "frozen" into rocks that comprise tectonic plates.  Convection is a turbulent process.  Tectonic plates move more or less randomly around on the surface of the Earth at the rate of ~ 10 cm per year, carrying their "frozen" magnetic fields with them.  As a result, the Earth's magnetic field is definitely not a simple dipole field.  The dipole component is not very well aligned with the rotational axis of the Earth, and even wanders somewhat randomly.  This [Scientific American article](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/what-causes-the-periodic/) gives a good presentation of the complexity of the processes that cause changes in the Earth's magnetic field.